# How do I give ngFor variable inside ngIf?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am having code like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let track_type of model.content_id.track_types">
    <label class="col-3">{{track_type}} Stream ID*:</label>
    <input type="text" name="stream_id_{{track_type}}" class="col-offset-1 col-3" #stream_id="ngModel" placeholder="{{track_type}} Stream ID" required [(ngModel)]="model.stream_id">
    <span *ngIf="stream_id.invalid && (stream_id.dirty || stream_id.touched)" class="col-offset-2 col-5 text-danger">Stream ID is required</span>
    <br>
</span>
```

There are two issues:

- If I edit one text box, it is affecting all the text boxes.
- It is unable to set the form validation properly

How do I resolve these issues? I tried looking at **ngTemplateOutlet**, but it's not really working as expected.

Comment: Harisha. if you has a loop, you need severals variables. Not only one. Normally it's used an array or a propertie of the object if we are iterating over an array of object. I don't know nothing about your model, but I supouse that you want say `[(ngModel)]="track_type"`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a trackByFunction

```
  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
  }
```

And in your template:

```
<span *ngFor="let track_type of model.content_id.track_types; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

Comment: this is not the problem

Comment: "If I edit one text box, it is affecting all the text boxes."  fix this